# Is it possible to translate Django ModelMultipleChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

My goal is to create a form that display multiple checkboxes and allows users to select one or more choices. All those choices need to be translated.

While using non-model driven form and `CHOICES` it works as expected.

```
COLOR_CHOICES = (
    (1, _('Red')),
    (2, _('Black')),
)
```

Since my form is model based instead of `MultipleChoiceField` I have to use `ModelMultipleChoiceField`.

```
colors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Colors.objects, # <- This needs to exist in the database so can't use CHOICES
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    required=False
)
```

Since `ModelMultipleChoiceField` queries the database to get the choices I have to have the data in the database in the first place.

I can think of two solutions to this problems but I am not sure how to make it work (possibly there is a different approach I am not aware of):

1. Create a fixture and translate it (translation is the problem here)
2. Use choices for the `queryset` in `ModelMultipleChoiceField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should translate `Colors` model. I send to you an active project that make easy the job:  [django-modeltranslation](http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/)

Learn more about this project is in my TODO list.

Also, take a look to [Dynamic Translation Apps for Django](http://www.muhuk.com/2010/01/dynamic-translation-apps-for-django/) from muhuk.com blog.

Comment: This is helpful. However, this add more complexity to fairly simple problem (in my opinion). Wouldn't it be better to use boolean fields instead of ModelMultipleChoiceField?